# STR_TO_DATE in MY SQL Query is Null

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I've read multiple posts and find nothing wrong with my syntax, can someone point out the error?

I am testing some queries in PHP MyAdmin, on a WordPress Database. The table I am querying has a meta_key of "Listing-End-Date" and meta_values of "2018/06/30".

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Listing-End-Date'
AND STR_TO_DATE('meta_value', '%Y/%m/%d') > CURDATE()
```

and it returns 0 results.  To test my STR_TO_DATE format, I did a new query:

```
SELECT `meta_key` , STR_TO_DATE( 'meta_value', '%Y/%m/%d' )
FROM 'table'
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Listing-End-Date'
```

I get the expected 1 result returned, but the date is NULL. Is it because I am using PHP My Admin or did I type something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta_value should be ticked and not quoted inside string_to_date

Comment: Thanks!I knew it had to be something painfully obvious. Removing the apostrophes (is that the same as a tick?) solved the problem. It seems that with all the pages and website and examples I see, they always omit something that must be obvious to everyone else

Comment: It will work without the ticks as you have found. But ticks are around meta_key in your above select. See the difference between those and the single quotes around listing_end_date?

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to convert string value `'meta_value'` to date which obviously fails. You probably wanted to reference a column `meta_value` from table `meta_key` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'Listing-End-Date'
AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d') > CURDATE()
```

I've removed backticks as they're not required here (all but `table`). Though, you really shouldn't name your table with a reserved keyword even if you can using backticks.

Also, one thing to note would be that `meta_key LIKE 'Listening-End-Date'` is equivalent of equality comparison `meta_key = 'Listening-End-Date'` because you don't do partial search (you're not using `%` anywhere).

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was the apostrophes (backticks?).  FYI, my table is not named table, but I didn't want to share its actual name.  As for using "LIKE," it was my understanding that LIKE is case in-sensitive and whereas an equal sign (=) is an exact match.  I use LIKE mostly due to my own fat fingers...I hate chasing down upper/lower case bugs. You would  think that by now I'd just put everything in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DATE_FORMAT()

[check this page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I have been to that page a hundred times.